# Python access dictionary inside list of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I have the below dictionary which has a value with a list, and inside the list is a dictionary. Is there a way to call the dictionary value inside the list using the key instead of the list index? The dictionary inside the list may vary so the index value may not always provide the right key value pair. But if I am able to use the key I can always get the correct value.

```
mylist = {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A'}, {'B': 'Letter C'}, {'C': 'Letter C'}]}
print(mylist['mydict'][0]['A'])
```

Current Output:

```
Letter A
```

Desired Query:

```
print(mylist['mydict']['A'])
Letter A
```

Comment: Why not just use a dict of dicts?

Comment: you cannot change the results of the desired query without changing the structure of your object.. With the current structure, the query would always raise an error.

Comment: Looks like you should do `mydicts = {k: dict(v) for k, v in mylist.items()}` then you get the structure you can use as `mydicts['mydict']['A']`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the moment you have 3 dictionaries inside a list inside a dictionary. Try the below instead:

```
my_nested_dictionary = {'mydict': {'A': 'Letter A', 'B': 'Letter C', 'C': 'Letter C'}}
print(my_nested_dictionary['mydict']['A'])
```

Comment: I looped through data to create this and used .append({key: value}) to create the list with the dictionary. Let me see if I can format it like this. This helps thanks.

Comment: In that case you can initialise `mylist = {'mydict': {}}` and use a `for` loop over `key` and `value` and have `mylist['mydict'][key] = value`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the code below:

```
mylist = {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A'}, {'B': 'Letter C'}, {'C': 'Letter C'}]}

for dictionary in mylist['mydict']:
   try:
      print(dictionary['A'])
   except KeyError:
      pass
```

```
'Letter A'
```

You iterate over a dictionaries inside your list, and then try to call your `A` key. You catch `KeyError` because in the dictionary key may be absent.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code to generate the new dict.

```
mylist = {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A'}, {'B': 'Letter C'}, {'C': 'Letter C'}]}
newDict={}
for item in mylist['mydict']:
    newDict.update(item)
mylist['mydict']=newDict
print(mylist['mydict']['A'])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a generator?

```
item = next(item['A'] for item in mylist['mydict'] if 'A' in item)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if your original data is formatted as:

```
mylist = {'mydict': {'A': 'Letter A','B': 'Letter C','C': 'Letter C'}}
```

so without the embedded list - which doesn't seem to add meaningful structure anyway?