# Accessing value which is in dictionary which is in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have the following list which contains a number of other lists and dictionaries within it:

```
market_book_result = [{'betDelay': 0,
  'bspReconciled': False,
  'complete': True,
  'crossMatching': True,
  'inplay': False,
  'isMarketDataDelayed': True,
  'lastMatchTime': '2019-03-11T11:40:44.078Z',
  'marketId': '1.156023330',
  'numberOfActiveRunners': 12,
  'numberOfRunners': 12,
  'numberOfWinners': 1,
  'runners': [{'adjustmentFactor': 62.5,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 1.42, 'size': 94.47},
      {'price': 1.41, 'size': 157.16},
      {'price': 1.4, 'size': 426.93}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 1.43, 'size': 52.36},
      {'price': 1.44, 'size': 166.83},
      {'price': 1.45, 'size': 99.06}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 1.44,
    'selectionId': 13079071,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 18.854,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 4.8, 'size': 18.28},
      {'price': 4.7, 'size': 18.45},
      {'price': 4.6, 'size': 22.06}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 5.0, 'size': 42.1},
      {'price': 5.1, 'size': 156.12},
      {'price': 5.2, 'size': 13.85}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 5.0,
    'selectionId': 13101666,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 4.702,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 23.0, 'size': 13.84},
      {'price': 20.0, 'size': 10.36},
      {'price': 19.0, 'size': 10.15}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 40.0, 'size': 18.11},
      {'price': 55.0, 'size': 55.07},
      {'price': 80.0, 'size': 24.04}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 29.0,
    'selectionId': 12412709,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 3.766,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 42.0, 'size': 14.78},
      {'price': 34.0, 'size': 19.57},
      {'price': 28.0, 'size': 10.28}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 50.0, 'size': 10.12},
      {'price': 80.0, 'size': 45.05},
      {'price': 90.0, 'size': 15.4}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 50.0,
    'selectionId': 15700821,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 2.853,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 27.0, 'size': 10.96},
      {'price': 22.0, 'size': 12.91},
      {'price': 21.0, 'size': 10.45}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 60.0, 'size': 12.13},
      {'price': 70.0, 'size': 20.02},
      {'price': 80.0, 'size': 35.05}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 38.0,
    'selectionId': 22652454,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 1.952,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 110.0, 'size': 12.61},
      {'price': 85.0, 'size': 13.66},
      {'price': 70.0, 'size': 11.09}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 730.0, 'size': 17.16},
      {'price': 1000.0, 'size': 2.38}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 250.0,
    'selectionId': 13264025,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 1.803,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 65.0, 'size': 11.25},
      {'price': 48.0, 'size': 14.92},
      {'price': 34.0, 'size': 19.39}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 95.0, 'size': 13.94},
      {'price': 140.0, 'size': 13.38},
      {'price': 230.0, 'size': 35.05}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 95.0,
    'selectionId': 13747442,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 1.43,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 370.0, 'size': 12.56},
      {'price': 140.0, 'size': 10.16},
      {'price': 100.0, 'size': 73.2}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 1000.0, 'size': 10.71}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 740.0,
    'selectionId': 20765364,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 1.148,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 130.0, 'size': 11.08},
      {'price': 95.0, 'size': 60.19},
      {'price': 65.0, 'size': 11.26}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 1000.0, 'size': 6.38}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 590.0,
    'selectionId': 15803027,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 0.369,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 1000.0, 'size': 30.95},
      {'price': 510.0, 'size': 16.54},
      {'price': 220.0, 'size': 82.29}],
     'availableToLay': [],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 1000.0,
    'selectionId': 21632638,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 0.352,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 370.0, 'size': 13.25},
      {'price': 270.0, 'size': 22.52},
      {'price': 200.0, 'size': 13.92}],
     'availableToLay': [{'price': 980.0, 'size': 11.83},
      {'price': 1000.0, 'size': 10.81}],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 940.0,
    'selectionId': 15715002,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0},
   {'adjustmentFactor': 0.273,
    'ex': {'availableToBack': [{'price': 1000.0, 'size': 245.38},
      {'price': 600.0, 'size': 14.33},
      {'price': 500.0, 'size': 37.24}],
     'availableToLay': [],
     'tradedVolume': []},
    'handicap': 0.0,
    'lastPriceTraded': 1000.0,
    'selectionId': 22760633,
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
    'totalMatched': 0.0}],
  'runnersVoidable': False,
  'status': 'OPEN',
  'totalAvailable': 891400.06,
  'totalMatched': 56244.82,
  'version': 2681378822}]
```

I can access the value for each key named price like such:

```
market_book_result[0]['runners'][0]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']

market_book_result[0]['runners'][1]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']

market_book_result[0]['runners'][2]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']
```

I would like to access each of these values using a for loop. To do this I have tried the following:

```
for i in market_book_result[0]['runners']:

    x = market_book_result[0]['runners'][i]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']

    print(x)
```

But this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

I have looked at this question [Python access dictionary inside list of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592268/python-access-dictionary-inside-list-of-a-dictionary?rq=1) and adjusted my code to the following:

```
 for dic in market_book_result[0]['runners']:
        for key,value in market_book_result[0]['runners'][dic]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price'].iteritems():
         print(value)
```

but this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

If anyone could help me access `market_book_result[0]['runners'][0]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']` for all 12 runners using a for loop that would be great.

Cheers, 
Sandy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While iterating like that, 'i' is already an element of runners (a dict and not an int). So you should do:

```
for runner in market_book_result[0]['runners']:
    x = runner['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']
    print(x)
```

EDIT: I renamed 'i' to 'runner' to be more readable, as suggested by "Philipp F".

Comment: Renaming `i` to `runner` makes the code more readable, I think.

Comment: a lot better than my answer below.

Comment: You are right Phillipp F, thanks! I have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
runners = market_book_result[0]['runners']
for runner in runners:
    items = runner['ex']['availableToBack']
    for item in items:
        print(item['price'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over a number or a range. As you have the number of runners stored in your dictionary, why not use this?

```
for i in range(market_book_result['numberOfRunners']):
  x = market_book_result[0]['runners'][i]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']
  print(x)
```

Comment: should be `market_book_result[0]['numberOfRunners']` instead of `market_book_result['numberOfRunners']`